Electron mouseWheel sendInputEvent not doing anything
I try to send a mouseWheel event to a BrowserWindow webContent with electron with the following code:
const wheelEvent = {
    type: 'mouseWheel',
    x: 100, // X-coordinate (optional)
    y: 100, // Y-coordinate (optional)
    deltaX: 0, // Horizontal scroll amount
    deltaY: 120, // Vertical scroll amount (e.g., 120 for one notch of scrolling)
};

// Send the event to the webview
win.webContents.sendInputEvent(wheelEvent, (result) => {
    if (!result.success) {
        console.log('Error sending input event:', result.error);
    }
});

but nothing happen, and I don't get any error. Is it because wheel events are not trusted ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/WheelEvent
In that case mouseWheel events are no longer working with electron ?
I am sure that the browser window has the focus before running the code.

Have you checked the status of the events using the DevTools?
By the way Pupeeteer might help. It generates trusted events.

const wheelEvent = {
    type: 'mouseWheel',
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    deltaX: 0,
    deltaY: -120, // <== You have to use negative numbers to scroll down.
};

